# Problem with PDE (Print Dialog Extension) on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, pde

I try to make PDE, but when I open a print dialog and want to select my pane I see only that message: "The package "MyPDE" could not be loaded because it contains no version for the current architecture.". I compiled it with different options for architectures, but didn't help. How should I make it? I have Mac OS X 10.6.8 and use Xcode 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set Valid Architectures to "ppc i386 x86_64" and Architectures for Debug to Standard (32/64-bit Intel) and now it works.